# How to change selected combobox item depanding on text instead of value in windows form application (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am developing a windows form application where I am trying to edit data of selected row in a Datagridview using textbox and combobox (dropdown) in windows form application. There is a column called status in Datagridview whose value is text (e.g. status = "start"). I need to change the prepopulate combobox depanding on the status column of selected row in the Datagridview.

I am getting null value in selectedvalue of combobox

```
combobox1.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Status"].Value.ToString();
```

Where

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Status"].Value.ToString() = "Start"
```

Is there a way to change the selected combobox option depanding on text instead of value in windows form application using C#?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have two columns inside a DataGridView: one containing text and one containing combo boxes, and you want the selected combo box element to change with the text.

I can't be overly specific because you haven't posted any code, but to get you started, you'll probably want to listen for a change in the text box column using an event handler:

```
myDataGridView.CellClick += myDataGridView_CellClick;

...

void myDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != TEXTBOX_COLUMN_ID) return;
    object value = myDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
}
```

The local variable value will then have whatever was entered into the textbox column. From there, you'll need to find the dropdown box in the same row (using e.RowIndex) and adjust its value however you wish.

Answer (score 0):

On the "CellClick" event, maybe you should feed in the row into a DataGridViewRow object, then say if that cell within the row selected contains "Start", run a function that populates the combobox?

ex:

```
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        if (row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString() == "Start")
        {
            //fill combobox with needed information
        }
```

Comment: I am trying to change an option in a prepoulated combobox.

Comment: @user3465750 have you tried setting the combobox.text property to the value that you would like to set it to? ex: comboBox1.Text = "Start";